# Write a query to find the highest salaried employee from table who is living in "Nagpur" in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I am having below tables with the data:

```
select * from Emp

EmpId   DeptId  Salary
101     1       3000
102     2       4000
103     3       3000
104     1       5000
105     2       7000
106     3       10000
107     3       20000
108     2       10000
109     1       10000

Select * from EmpDetail
EmpId   Name    Role    City
101     Rick    QA      Nagpur
102     John    Dev     Pune
103     Jane    Dev     Mumbai
104     Rock    QA      Pune
105     Shane   Manager Mumbai
106     Peter   Dev     Nagpur
107     Jackob  Manager Nagpur
108     Jeff    QA      Pune
109     Bob     Dev     Nagpur
```

So the question is how to find to find the highest salaried employee from table who is living in "Nagpur" in sql server?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Think about how you'd solve this if you had to do it manually  Select all of the employees who live in "Nagpur".  Use that information to help you select Salary information.  Now, order that information by Salary, and order it from highest to lowest.  Then take just one item from the top of that list (the one with the largest salary). You can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should do the job**

```
select top 1 ed.*, e.salary form Emp e INNER JOIN EmpDetail ed
ON e.ID=ed.ID
WHERE ed.City='Nagpur' 
order by e.Salary desc
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Emp(EmpId,DeptId,Salary)
AS
(
SELECT 101,1,3000  Union all
SELECT 102,2,4000  Union all
SELECT 103,3,3000  Union all
SELECT 104,1,5000  Union all
SELECT 105,2,7000  Union all
SELECT 106,3,10000 Union all
SELECT 107,3,20000 Union all
SELECT 108,2,10000 Union all
SELECT 109     ,1       ,10000
)
,EmpDetail(EmpId,Name,Role,City)
AS
(
SELECT 101,'Rick'  ,'QA'      ,'Nagpur'  Union all
SELECT 102,'John'  ,'Dev'     ,'Pune'    Union all
SELECT 103,'Jane'  ,'Dev'     ,'Mumbai'  Union all
SELECT 104,'Rock'  ,'QA'      ,'Pune'    Union all
SELECT 105,'Shane' ,'Manager' ,'Mumbai'  Union all
SELECT 106,'Peter' ,'Dev'     ,'Nagpur'  Union all
SELECT 107,'Jackob','Manager' ,'Nagpur'  Union all
SELECT 108,'Jeff'  ,'QA'      ,'Pune'    Union all
SELECT 109,'Bob'   ,'Dev'     ,'Nagpur'  
)
SELECT TOP 1 E.EmpId
    ,D.NAME
    ,D.ROLE
    ,E.DeptId
    ,MAx(E.Salary) Salary
    ,D.City
FROM EmpDetail D
INNER JOIN Emp E ON E.EmpId = D.EmpId
WHERE D.City = 'Nagpur'
GROUP BY E.EmpId
    ,D.NAME
    ,D.ROLE
    ,E.DeptId
    ,D.City
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

OutPut

```
EmpId   NAME    ROLE    DeptId  Salary  City
---------------------------------------------
107    Jackob   Manager 3       20000   Nagpur
```